# Prevent Spacemacs from creating double sr-speedbar

Tags: spacemacs, commands, speedbar

I'm trying to make **Spacemacs** and **sr-speedbar** work together smoothly.

**Without using Spacemacs**:

The command buffer is local to each buffer where it is called:
[image]

Left is sr-speedbar, right is the main buffer.

If invoke command buffer from sr-speedbar buffer, then it is local to sr-speedbar buffer:

[image]

Left is sr-speedbar, right is the main buffer.

**After using Spacemacs:**
The command buffer is occupying both of the windows, 
[image]

And possibly because of this feature, oftentimes, it creates two sr-speedbar buffers, which is very annoying, using list-fontsets:
[image]

So how to roll back the command buffer to make them act like normal to prevent creating two sr-speedbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved after specifying distribution as base instead of the default one.

```
dotspacemacs-distribution 'spacemacs-base
```

The problem occurs because of the layer spacemacs-ui-visual, but by disabling it, cannot see the spaceline.

Further investigation has shown that the package conflicting with sr-speedbar is the package `popwin`, so exclude this package in .spacemacs would solve the problem and can still use spaceline.